# Disable a div in AngularJS with ng-click property?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I need to disable a div in AngularJS depend on a condition. Yes I can do it by using css change (giving low contrast and less color appearance) in appearance but I have ng-click property in it. So I need to prevent that calling also. How can I do it?

Here is my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list.items" ng-click="goToFunction()" ng-disabled="true">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ng-disabled does not work for div. It will for each html element which support the disable property (eg : input). 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

I created a simple fiddle to demonstrate how to achieve it with a simple div http://jsfiddle.net/5Qc5k/1/

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $templateCache) {
    $scope.isDisabled = false;
    $scope.alertMe = function(){
        if($scope.isDisabled === true){
            return;
        }
        // disable the function
        $scope.isDisabled = true;


        alert("foo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in controller ie:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list.items" ng-click="goToFunction(item)" ng-disabled="true">
```

and after that in controller:

```
 function goToFunction(item){
   if(item.condition == disable){
      return false
   }
   else {

          // do something
       }
}
```

Comment: Hi you don't have to use disable, in your html just use <div ng-repeat="item in list.items" ng-click="goToFunction(item)" > if you want to add some css to disable div try this <div ng-repeat="item in list.items" ng-click="goToFunction(item)" ng-class=""{'enabled' : !item.disabled, 'disabled' : item.disabled}""

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the ng-click functionality based on disable you can do in following:-

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list.items" ng-disabled="item.condition" ng-click="goToFunction(item)">
  item.value
</div>

$scope.goToFunction = function(item){
  if(item.condition == false){
    // Dont do anything
  }else{
    //do something
  }
```

In this scenario when div is disabled, click functionality wont do anything, otherwise it will do.